# Show a 503 error page if server unavailable

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect

I've searched through google, stackoverflow and serverfault but I'm not quite sure how to phrase what I'm looking for, sorry if this is a duplicate (it probably is)!

What I would like to know is if its possible to do the following:

I currently have access to two different servers (droplets) with Digital Ocean under two accounts, one account is for development work and the other is actually hosting a site.
Both run a LAMP stack.

So the setup is like this

---

## Development Server

Account1

Server1

IP (example) 1.1.1.1

---

---

## Website Server

Account2

Server2

IP (example) 2.2.2.2

---

The website server has its DNS records all setup correctly (A Record, and CNAME record and nameserver details).

What I would like to achieve, is to host a 503 page on my development server, so when I power down apache and/or the whole VM for maintenence/installing/updating, that anyone who tries to access our domain is automatically redirected to a 503 page.

EG. Someone tries to access www.domain.com, which would resolve to 2.2.2.2, however, if 2.2.2.2 is unreachable, redirect to 1.1.1.1/503.html, or too 503.1.1.1.1 if it has to use sub-domain.

Because the server may be off, htaccess or php header-redirects aren't an option.

I think this might be possible using a 3rd server to monitor the status of 2.2.2.2 and redirecting when not available, but I don't want the extra overhead if possible.

Is this possible?

I don't want to use replication (just yet anyway) as the site is still in its early days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it without an additional device. You need to have something upstream which is fielding the requests and passing them on to the relevant servers. When it detects that something has gone away then it returns the 503.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my fears @Iain, I thought that might of been the only way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Iain's answer is broadly correct and it is sensible to use an upstream proxy, such as nginx, to handle the problem. However, another solution is to add a virtual IP (VIP) to the pair of servers, see the URL's below.

http://krystianekb.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/linux-configuring-single-cluster-vip.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-keepalived-lvs-cluster-configuration/

This solution can be implemented on your own infrastructure, when you have full control. I am not certain if it can be done on your cloud hosted virtual machines, because of restrictions of the cloud infrastructure. However, Digital Oceans support could inform you if this approach is usable on their systems.

The main web server would be the master, the one that grabs the IP address whenever it can. The backup web server would serve up the 503 page when it acquires the VIP, after the master goes offline.

Note that this system would not failover the VIP when the master is up, but the web server on the master is not running, but the VIP would failover if the master is turned off or if you manually failover the VIP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without another device: using a short TTL in your DNS zone, you could migrate to another IP (like 1.1.1.1) when 2.2.2.2 is not answering.

To achieve that, you'll need a service (that could be hosted on 1.1.1.1) which will do that :

- check if 2.2.2.2 is answering
- if not, change the DNS to 1.1.1.1
- if yes, change the DNS to 2.2.2.2

That said, your users will have "no answer at all" (not even a 503) during TTL seconds when switching. If your planned downtime of 2.2.2.2 are big, this is a solution. If you want immediate switch, you'll need another device (called a failover / load-balancer)